# Tensorflow doubts about the (input) dimensions of a model when predicting the class of a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm trying to implement an irony detection model.
My dataset consists of tweets labeled with a 1 or a 0 to indicate whether they're ironic or not.

After the preprocessing, tokenization and padding phases I'm left with fixed-length sequences and an associated vector of labels to split in training and test set and feed as input to the model. The sequences are in the following form:

```py
>>> data
array([[    1,   677,   348, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [    1,   677,   348, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [    1,   825,     1, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       ...,
       [  908,  1376,   686, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [    8,   158, 14579, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [    1,     1,    35, ...,     0,     0,     0]], dtype=int32)

>>> data.shape
(3977, 50)
>>> data[0].shape
(50,)
```

The model is the following one:

```py
num_words = len(tok.word_index) + 1 # tok is a Tokenizer which I fit on the data

import tensorflow as tk
from tensorflow import keras
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)

# The model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, 64, input_length=Config.SEQUENCE_LENGTH, mask_zero=True))
model.add(keras.layers.GRU(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.GRU(64))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

After compiling the model with `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])` and splitting the dataset with `sklearn`'s utility functions I call the fit method of the model:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

After training the model, the `evaluate` method works as expected, taking as input `x_test` and `y_test` but if I call the `model.predict_classes(x_test[0])` (or `(model.predict(x_test[0]) > 0.5).astype("int32")`) instead of a single prediction I get a (50,1)-shaped array of predictions. **I tried reshaping x_test[0] in this way `model.predict_classes(x_test[0].reshape(1,50))` and I get a single prediction inside an array: `array([[1]], dtype=int32)`**

So now I'm left with the following questions (also due to the fact that I get a 0.6 accuracy when calling `evaluate(x_test, y_test)`:

- Why if I pass the dataset to the model as an array of arrays (x_train), I cannot just pass an element of the test set to the predict function (e.g. `x_test[0]`) but I have to reshape it instead?
- **Is it normal** or is there some error? Am I setting the input dimensions of the model wrong? Should I reshape the sequences also before feeding them to the model?

Comment: By inspection of your codes, you are doing things correctly except that you have some confusion regarding the inference part. Please also provide the shape of labels.

Comment: `y_train.shape` yields `(3181,)` while `y_test.shape` yields `(796,)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why if I pass the dataset to the model as an array of arrays
> (x_train), I cannot just pass an element of the test set to the
> predict function (e.g. x_test[0]) but I have to reshape it instead?

It is because `model.predict` can only accept **a set of** examples rather than a single example and if you want to supply a single example into it, you have to reshape it into `(1,50)`, so that it is **a set of** example where the size of the set is 1.

However, instead of feeding in examples one by one into `model.predict`, it is more efficient to feed in a set of examples into `model.predict`, i.e. `pred_test = model.predict(x_test)` and afterwards if you want to know the prediction of the ith example, do `prediction_of_the_ith_example = pred_test[i]`

> Is it normal or is there some error? Am I setting the input dimensions
> of the model wrong? Should I reshape the sequences also before feeding
> them to the model?

The model definition and the training part is correct.

Regarding the shape of labels(`y_train` and `y_test`), the correct shape to use is (data_size,label_length), i.e. `(3181,1)` and `(796,1)` respectively. You are doing single label classification here, so that the label length is 1. But even if you used `(3181,)` and `(796,)`, it worked properly just because it did automatic broadcasting for you.